# C# Warning: Variable is assigned but never used

Tags: c#, warnings

I see this warning in a lot of places in my code because of a specific paradigm I keep using throughout.  Within objectA, I create objectB and objectB does a lot of it's own work that is necessary, but not referenced anywhere else.

The only answers to this question I see are:

- Suppress the warning
- You are doing something wrong.

Example of what I'm doing in lots of places.

```
class A {
    B b;
    public A() { 
        b = new B(); 
    }
}

class B {
    public B() {
        Updater.RegisterForSuperImportantUpdates(this);
    }

    public void Update() { 
        // super important stuff happening here 
        ....
    }
}
```

Does this seem like a valid design or is there an off putting odor here.  Suppressing the warning is going to be annoying because this pattern is going to be used frequently.

Comment: You can avoid that warning by using `Debug.Log(b)`.

Comment: Which line is getting the warning here? That `b` isn't used? Who invokes `Update` on b? If `Updater.RegisterForSuperImportantUpdates(this)` is calling it - that's a code smell. Mainly because you're storing a reference to `b` (but you don't need to) - but also because a constructor should set up the object's internals - it shouldn't have side effects

Comment: *you're storing a reference to b (but you don't need to)*, so the simplest way to get rid of the warning is make `B` a static class, that way there are no references (of it not being set). Unless there is a good reason to have multiple instances of a class used for Updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to keep a reference to b(B) if you are not using it after? 
Can't you just new it without keeping it referenced?

As it seems to be referenced by a third class not mentioned here (`Updater`), it should not be GCeed.

Comment: Good point. Just seemed like bad practice to new something up without keeping a reference. Maybe this will be a good solution. I do worry that my design may cause bugs down the line if I do it this way and then, say if I have other subclasses of B that change the constructor which will no longer have the reference and in turn will cause it to get GCed.  Thanks for the response I'll mark it as a solution but a potential refactoring of my code may be in order.

Answer (score -1):

It is a valid warning , as per clean code principle , you should keep your code as much neat and clean such that the second person who will be going to fix in your code should not confused with the unused variable used in the code.